# What are these buttons on the edge of my Pixel 5 / Android 13 screen and how do I remove them?

Tags: menu, android-13

There is a button menu on the edge of my stock Pixel 5 / Android 13 screen that do nothing and are constantly in the way, but I can't figure out how to make it go away. Probably the same problem that is preventing them from launching an app is also preventing configuration.

I don't know what these buttons are called, so I haven't been able to search the web for a solution. So here is a screenshot. The buttons are on the center-right edge of the screen:

[image: screen shot of buttons]

The buttons are the icons of apps I have installed. They show up not just on the home screen, but on every screen of every app. I can move the position of this menu around the screen by dragging it, but it is otherwise inert.

Is this an add-on app that you recognize, that I might uninstall to make these go away? Thanks!

Comment: They look to match two of the icons on your screen - what I believe to be Vive Manager and 1Password - so it is probably some other third-party app showing you recents or shortcuts of some kind. Do the icons there change? Does it show over all screens or just the home screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Those are *accessibility shortcut* buttons.** They are used to quickly *toggle* (i.e. switch off/on) the related accessibility features.

To configure these, go to the Accessibility settings:

1. Open Settings
2. Navigate to Accessibility
3. Tap the related accessibility app (e.g. 3rd-party apps under "Downloaded apps", otherwise scroll below for built-in accessibilities)
4. Tap the shortcut switch to show/hide the shortcut button

Comment: I went to "Accessibility Menu" within the "Accessibility" settings. There is an option for "Accessibility Menu shortcut", but it is already set to "Off". Are you sure that these are accessibility shortcuts? If so why are they still on?

Comment: @Mori sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant in step 3 is to tap the related accessibility app, which I assume there is an entry for VIVE and another app under "Downloaded apps".

Comment: Nice! I thought it looked like the accessibility button, but didn't realize you could turn it on per-app. Good one!